# Load online images in <img> tag with itext

Tags: java, android, html, itext

I'm using `XMLWorker` in itextpdf library to convert xHTML to pdf.

In the xHTML content there is some  tag with local storage images and images from the Internet.

Eg:

```
<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" alt="W3Schools.com" style="width:104px;height:142px;"/>
```

With the local images, I have implemented `ImageProvider` to provide the resource root path. 
But with these images from the Internet, it cannot be loaded.

I tried to override `Image retrieve(String src)` method of AbstractImageProvider to load images from the Internet, but I got `NetworkOnMainThread` exception.
I don't know how to use AsyncTask or any other wars to load online images and return it inside `Image retrieve(String src)`.

I've searched in the Internet and people only use `ImageProvider` with local images. Any ideas for me?

Comment: Add some codes of your `ImageProvider`

Comment: Only some methods to get Image from the url provided. But it violate NetworkOnMainThread. And I don't know how to use Asynctask to return Image in retrieve method

Comment: That happens because you were trying to request a network on thread "main". I don't really understand your use-case, but if you want to implement AsyncTask in your class, try to call network in `doInBackground()` and populate the result in `onPostExecuted()`. Remember to call execute(). If that is a very long request, use `ThreadPoolExecutor` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Until now, I tried to wrap the whole process of conversion from HTML to PDF inside a "big" AsyncTask.

It's work for now, but the code is a bit ugly because it cause code coupling and hard to extend later on for supporting other conversion types.

Comment: hi @nhoxbypass , I met the same problem like you here, would I know if you get the final solution?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your question without context. This may be fit with your question.

Create a callback inside your `ImageProvider`. Then every time `AsyncTask` (or anything that helps you make a request) gives the response, trigger it.

```
public class ImageProvider {
private OnImageProviderCallback callback;

public ImageProvider(OnImageProviderCallback callback) {
    this.callback = callback;
}

public OnImageProviderCallback getCallback() {
    return callback;
}

public void setCallback(OnImageProviderCallback callback) {
    this.callback = callback;
}

public interface OnImageProviderCallback {
    void onRetrievedImage(Image image);
}

public void retrive() {
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Image>() {
        @Override
        protected Image doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            // request for image here
            If(request.success()) {
                return request.getImage();
            }else{
                // Handle error
                return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Image image) {
            super.onPostExecute(image);
            callback.onRetrievedImage(image);
        }
    }.execute();
}
}
```

Then in your `activity` , make it done by calling this

```
new ImageProvider(new ImageProvider.OnImageProviderCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onRetrievedImage(Image image) {
            // do something with your image
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, but the function need to be override is Image retrieve(String src). It must return an Image, not "void" return type. So I cannot use AsyncTask inside this method.

I tried to wrap the whole conversion to PDF progress inside a "big" AsyncTask. It's work for now, but the code is a bit ugly